# Cuba on Tomcat proxied by Nginx

Tags: nginx, cuba-platform

I'm having a very hard time trying to configure nginx as a proxy to Tomcat running Cuba Platform. I use Nginx for SSL.

Nginx directive:

```
server {
    server_name test.domain.it   www.test.domain.it;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/test.domain.it.access.log rt_cache;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/test.domain.it.error.log;
    root /var/www/test.domain.it/htdocs/PHPApp/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    include common/php7.conf;  
    include common/locations-php7.conf;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.domain.it/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.domain.it/privkey.pem;

    location /board {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_read_timeout     3600;
        proxy_connect_timeout  240;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-RealIP $remote_addr;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/board;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

tomcat/conf/board/local.app.properties:

```
cuba.webHostName = test.domain.it
cuba.webAppUrl = https://test.domain.it/board
cuba.webContextName = board
```

tomcat/conf/board-core/local.app.properties:

```
cuba.webHostName = test.domain.it
cuba.automaticDatabaseUpdate = true
cuba.webAppUrl = https://test.domain.it/board
```

Nginx access log:

```
82.60.41.71 0.010 - [31/Mar/2017:15:13:21 +0200] test.k-rev.it "GET /board HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.110 Safari/537.36"
82.60.41.71 0.015 - [31/Mar/2017:15:13:21 +0200] test.k-rev.it "GET /board/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1033 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.110 Safari/537.36"
```

Tomcat access log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Mar/2017:10:48:40 +0200] "GET /board HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Mar/2017:10:48:40 +0200] "GET /board/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2349
```

Above I used "domain" instead of the actual domain.
As you can see from the server directive, I already have a PHP application on the root.

I already tried several options with no luck. **I can access Tomcat, but I get the popup "Failed to load the bootstrap javascript: ./VAADIN/vaadinBootstrap.js?v2017_03_24_15_29"**

Accessing Tomcat from the outside on port 8080 without ssl works fine.

Comment: Check the access log - tomcat may be attempting to load its resources without providing the `/board/` prefix.

Comment: The only log I get referring to the request is by nginx

Comment: What Is the log entry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend that you use the same /path in tomcat for your application and then you can set up location as:

```
location /board {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/board;
}
```

See also: https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-6.4/server_push_settings.html for correct web-socket push configuration

Comment: Should I also set cuba.webHostName and cuba.webAppUrl in this case? To the public facing hostname?

Comment: I'm also getting 404 on board/VAADIN/resources/jquery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js , board/VAADIN/vaadinPush.js?v2017_03_28_11_25. I currently have ssl configured on nginx but tried also without it, the error is the same

Comment: If I expose Tomcat to the public everything is working fine. There must be something wrong on the proxy configuration, but after having followed all the instructions I still get the original error

Comment: @gmlion please edit the question and write your actual cuba host-related settings, nginx proxy configuration and nginx logs

Comment: Despite my problem being some conflicting settings elsewhere in nginx, this is the correct way to proxy cuba behind nginx